# Scraping data from Angular binding: where do the data come from?

Tags: angular, web-scraping

I'm trying to understand where the highlighted figures in the picture come from. I could understand that they are managed by a framework called Angular and that they are not present in any data sent over the network. So I guess they are calculated. How can I debug it?

ps: I'm not a web developer, I'm interested to scrape the highlighted values but Selenium is not working (probably for the antibot cloudflare defense).

https://www.etoro.com/discover/markets/cryptocurrencies

[image]

Comment: "not working" doesn't mean anything. Please post code and explain why it's not working. Error message? Can't find the element?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid there are already some opened question about issues with Selenium and etoro, it would  be a duplicate.. here I prefer to ask about this other possible solution, but there is no code. I tried to download 3 plugins for debugging angular but after a few hours I still can't get how the binding are working.

Comment: There's still no actual explanation of a problem.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid hope now it's more clear. I'm asking a basic question about Angular applied in this specific context.

Comment: You need a user name to log in and see that site. Regardless, that data is sent from somewhere. Press F12 in your browser. Go to the elements tab. Drill down until you find your data item. 0.09 is either present in the HTML, so it can be scraped, or it's represented as a picture, in which case it can't be scraped.